# Should "Hot Network Questions" show questions from non-English-language sites if you're on an English-language site?

Tags: bug, status-completed, languages, hot-questions

Sometimes "Hot Network Questions" will show posts from non-English sites, even when you're on an English-language site:

[image]

This is a low-priority issue, but should it be considered correct behavior?

Comment: It's not going to be in English if you follow the link. I think clicking a link whose text is in English and ending up on a site in a completely different language would be confusing/jarring.

Comment: @BSMP For clarification, both the question title and the question itself are non-English (the question is posted on a non-English-Language site).

Comment: It's a question on the network which "The Algorithm" has determined to be "hot".  I'm not sure what expectation of language exists here...but you do raise a fair point.

Comment: I thought you were suggesting translating the text if you're on an English site, which I thought was a bad idea. Are you actually suggesting they not be shown at all? Plenty of users seem to be able to speak multiple languages.

Comment: @BSMP Yes, I'm suggesting that they not be shown at all.

Comment: [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94526/354058)

Comment: Just because you are on the english version of SO does not mean you only know english.  I wouldn't mind this being an option in the profile but I do not think they should be blocked for everyone.

Comment: Related: [HNQ has been hacked by the Russians](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296686/230261)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site wasn't marked as a potential source of non-English questions, so the usual "English check" didn't run; I've corrected this. Going forward, questions from [Spanish Language Stack Exchange](https://spanish.stackexchange.com) will only show in the hot list if they contain some non-trivial amount of English.

Comment: That was fast :)

Comment: How does this about Spanish.SE combine with this [answer from Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272752/209901) related to SOes? He said _I flipped the relevant site setting on, so SOes questions should be dropped the next time the sidebar list refreshes_. Does this mean that he turned on the "English check" or that SOes is completely blocked from the hot network posts list?

Comment: Probably the same thing I wrote above, but for SOes, @fedorqui.

Comment: Thanks, Shog9! I don't remember seeing any question from SOes in the HNQ bar, but this can also be because they don't vote much over there.

Comment: Well, since we remembered to turn that setting on about a month after the site went public, there'd have been less opportunity to observe.

Answer (score 9):

> should it be considered correct behavior?

I think it should. For one, sticking to your screenshot, I wager that the share of users who know or care about the morphology of "desnudo" is no smaller than those aware of EPSG:3867 or Security Patch SUPEE-9767.